# Not able to access JSP request and session objects when using tinyMCE editor

Tags: jsp, tinymce, request

I was using a textarea for taking user text input, but in order to retain the text formatting decided to try out tinyMCE.

What I need to do:

1. Save the input entered into the tinyMCE editor to the database by posting the content to a servlet.
2. Retrieve the saved text from the server and display it in the tinyMCE for any editing.

Problem Description:
This is how I sent the text retrieved from the server to the front end JSP:

```
request.setAttribute('inputText',txt);
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/TextareaTest.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

In the JSP page I use JSTL/EL only. So to access the value in the request object I use
    ${requestScope['inputText']} or ${inputText}

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var txt = "${requestScope['inputText']}";
tinyMCE.get('textarea1').setContent(txt);
</script>
```

But this does not work with tinyMCE. Somehow I am not able to access the request object like I was able to before integrating tinyMCE. If I remove tinyMCE, it works fine. But now its like a normal textarea.

need to figure out how to access the value set on the request object by the servlet inside the javascript function.

Thanks

Comment: might be a permission specific problem. check if the document.domain of all frames on your page differ

Comment: Hey, based on your comment it seems tinyMCE might be creating a different frame and the original request object is not available in this frame. http://www.hansbergsten.com/how-to-pass-request-parameters-to-frame-pages/.  But how do I solve this, since I am not manually defining the frames.

Comment: yes, tinymce creates a contenteditable iframe like most rte in order to be able to apply styles. the tinymce iframe is adressable using $('iframe#'+'your_editot_id'+'ift')

Comment: ok, I just need to send a value from my servlet to this tinyMCE editor. Could you suggest another way to do this instead of using the requestScope since, I cannot pass the request parameters to an IFrame that I am not creating. Thanks

Comment: depends, in case this value is available before the editor gets initialized i think i know a way

Comment: I got it to work. I was trying to call the save() on the editor instance which seemed to be causing the problem. I removed that and am able to access the sessionScope. Now there is a another problem: If I enter text in two lines by clicking enter.. this is what is sent to the server "<p>hello 1</p>
<p>hello again</p>". Now when I retrieve it and try to display this in the editor, it fails. If I stick to content on a single line, it works. Is there some additional formatting that I need to do on my end?

Comment: maybe you need to remove crlf before you insert the content

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I was trying to call the save() on the editor instance which seemed to be causing the problem. I removed that and am able to access the sessionScope